# passing url query string parameters to SSRS Report in SharePoint 2007 integrated mode

Tags: reporting-services, url, query-string

Is there some trick to doing this? Most guides suggest I just add the parameter to the url address, but that does not see to work.  Is this a SharePoint 2007 issue?

Comment: Is the SSRS report set up to receive parameters and use the values in the report?

Comment: Yes. Right now parameter are set to prompt. No switch set like hidden or internal. I notice we can pass params to other reports using the .NET reportviewer control, but how do we pass params in a url if the report is running under SharePoint.

Comment: just noticed for non sharepoint reports we run reportviewer.aspx, how and where would we do this in SharePoint? I can run the report in sharepoint with no problem, just can't pass it params in url. I can also run the report from native SSRS and pass it params if running reportviewer.aspx.